# Can't edit any questions?

Tags: discussion, edits

It appears that the `edit` link is disabled on every post for me. Is it possible to be edit banned, and if so why would I be?

Comment: Try hovering over the edit link and see what it says...

Comment: A significant number of your suggestions seem to have been rejected. That might explain it. In which case you'll have to wait for a week.

Comment: Is there a way to see that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2026321/ian-carroll?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: How can I see what ones were rejected?

Comment: Click on the suggested edit links

Answer (score 9):

The answer is in your [profile's about box](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2026321/ian-carroll):

> I am a grammar nazi and will hunt down your Thanks! at the bottom of your posts.

Don't.

Almost all [your recent edit suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2026321/ian-carroll?tab=activity) were just removing "hi", "thanks" and similar from posts, and nothing else. Those were *very* minor edits, and most of them were rejected as such, which lead to the edit ban. I don't want to discourage you from editing, but please try to make more substantial edits. Your suggestions need to be reviewed by at least three people, and their time is as valuable as anyone else's, no point in wasting it to review an edit that just removes "thanks".

Comment: Ok. I'll try and clear up everything next time

Comment: @IanCarroll Please do that. I'm not saying that you should fix  _everything_ that needs to be fixed in a post, no one's is going to bark at you because you missed something. But suggested edits like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1957391) are... not really what edits are for. It's perfectly ok to focus only on grammar, spelling and removing "thanks" and "hi", but don't just edit to fix one silly thing.